# Circular dependency in Authorization class

Tags: magento2, php

Magento 2.4.2-p1

PHP 7.4

I've noticed that I get a fatal error allowed memory when I hit any Magento's rest API like

> rest/default/V1/guest-carts/zg9WgsI6iTxvcA9YzPQnWqDNr7CLYVy2/estimate-shipping-methods

in the cart and checkout page, I disabled some modules and I saw there is a circular dependency in these 2 class

> Exception #0 (LogicException): Circular dependency:
> Magento\Framework\Authorization depends on
> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Authorization and vice versa.

My question is, why could I have this error in these 2 Magento's classes?, they are part of the vendor and I didn't touch them

Comment: which modules did you disable?

Comment: Modules that I created

Comment: also, in the __construct of `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Authorization.php`

this was the original

`public function __construct(AuthorizationInterface $authorization, ProductFactory $factory)
    {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->productFactory = $factory;
    }
`
I removes the AuthorizationInterface and it started to work 

`public function __construct(ProductFactory $factory)
    {
        $this->productFactory = $factory;
    }
`